# How to invest in art?

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies

What are the ways people can/do people invest in art?

Or what strategies are there?

In company investment, off the top of my head,  you can:

1. Invest in index/managed funds
2. Invest in start ups/rising stars (IPOs, VC)
3. Invest in companies which seem undervalued (e.g., Warren Buffett)
4. Day trading (making bets/arbartrarging info/time

Only 2 and maybe 3 seem possible with art investment.

Is that correct, or are there 'managed funds' of art investments?

Comment: There do appear to be... this [Art Fund Association](http://www.artfundassociation.com/_what_are_art_funds/basic_af.html) page may be of help/interest.

Comment: Can you reword the question. Are you asking about how to invest in art work like paintings, jewelry, sculptures, ancient items that are expected to rise in value?

Comment: [Entire books have been written on the subject](http://amzn.eu/d/ixDVOFp)

Comment: There's no such thing as investing in art. It's like investing into playing roulette. You're merely gambling.

Comment: hi @Davor - it could be you are thinking of something else, or have bad information.    Investing in theoretical intangibles (ie: stocks) is simply gambling (like guessing on horse racing).  Investing in tangibles (ie - basically antiques) is totally tangible and real.  For example you can *literally state* how many Vermeers or Picassos there are in the universe.  Only real estate is similarly as tangible (although real estate can be taken away from you any second by the local sovereign authority - you never really own it.) ...

Comment: By all means fads go up and down, as with any investment (brown furniture is in a long term slump; classical paintings are going nothing but up for decades).  I've made a fortune (well, everything's relative!) from tangibles as have many folks.  It's completely normal, the norm, for wealthy families (not me!) to secure wealth with tangibles.   If you are thinking of the fads in **modern art** , yes that is a dead risky/flakey "investment" - almost as flakey as stocks or commodities.  (But that just means it's "hard" to win in - large numbers of people have made epic fortunes in modern art.)

Comment: This question is a little too broad in my opinion. If you could narrow the scope significantly, I think it could stay open, but you are asking a lot of questions here.

Comment: AFAIC, the Greater Fool Theory applies to art.  It's not what it's worth but what someone is willing to pay for it.  A classic example is Jackson Pollock who 'threw' paint at a canvas during his "drip period."  $140 mil for one of these???  (eye roll) Yes, I'm an art heretic.

Comment: @Fattie - casino chips are as tangible as any art piece. Tangibility has absolutelly nothing to do with whether something is gambling or not.

Comment: hey @Davor , the key point is, "investing" rofl in stocks is, literally, exactly gambling. But when you mention "gambling" the issue is not germaine to the literal question.

Comment: hi @BobBaerker - whilst humorous, you somewhat confusingly conflate "modern art" ("bizarre, often apparently trivial, pictures by modern artists such as Warhol, Rothko etc") with the whole issue of "investing in tangible art" (which could be paintings from the 1600s which you would probably "like", as it were, antiques, sculpture ancient, european, asian or modern, pre-raphs, etc etc).  Secondly you are surely aware that the entirety of stock investing is "greater fool" (if you wish to put it that way) paradigm.

Comment: It's bizarre this was voted closed - the question "is there an index fund for art works" is completely straigthtforward and on topic.

Comment: Hey @Fattie.  Not to sound snarky but I would have to know something about art in order to conflate anything about it, let alone care much about it.  Appreciation of the physical appearance of art is a separate issue from its "value".  While I am surely aware that the entirety of stock investing is "greater fool theory", until art pays quarterly dividends, I'll stick with equities :->)

Comment: Right, I think various "wealth category" (bullion!  real estate!  paintings!  stocks!  penny stocks!  VC!) surely has a lot of passionate love/hate around it .. it's worse than a Mac/Windows debate in the old days  :)  It is an astute point that (the few) stocks which pay dividends .. that is a specific advantage.  Real estate has overwhelming tax advantages (in most jurisdictions today), my acquaintances who make zillions from "classic cars" take them out for a spin, I accidentally drank all the investment wine, etc  :)  Viva la difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the ways people can/do people invest in art?

You invest in art by purchasing art.  Christie's and Sotheby's are the two "world-famous" auctioneers of antiques, "old" art (for want of a term) and modern art, but there are many regional auction houses and specialists in almost everything (whether "vintage cars", "books", etc etc etc). There's also (for want of a better term) "novelty" art, things like baseball cards, cels from Animes, etc etc (some of which have performed incredibly well indeed over the last century)

> What strategies are there?

The strategy to all investing is that

1. you **guess** what you think will go up.  (Example: real estate: you think Seattle real estate is going up and LA real estate is going down.)
2. you then **buy** that thing.  (In the example, you'd buy Seattle real estate.)

This is the only "strategy" to investing.  You are guessing what will go up.

This applies identically whether you are investing in real estate, antiques, art, stocks, commodities, gems, wine, or any other category.

> index/managed funds...

Yes, there are many "art" funds in all sorts of categories (antiques, gems, modern art, classical art, etc etc).

Don't forget that stocks (ie, the world's couple thousand biggest stocks) are very **liquid**, and things like physical gold are very liquid; whereas real estate and "art" is less liquid.  It can take ages to sell some land or say paintings.

(Similarly things like stocks/bullion have very low transaction costs, whereas physical tangibles (houses, Picassos etc) usually have high transaction costs.)

Conversely, "art" (antiques, paintings, etc etc) are tangible (they are absolutely real - precisely *N* Vermeers exist, and that's it) whereas stock instruments are just a thin-air abstraction.

Hence,

> day trading

as you imply there is really no "day trading" of tangibles to speak of.  One example is the market in wine (whether "futures" or cases); which was pretty hot for awhile and you could trade it in a rapid, day-trading-esque manner.  But yes there is really no fast, day-trading analogue for tangibles like antiques or real estate.  (That being said there are REITs which you can trade pretty fast, but they fall apart in banking/real estate crisis.)

The raison d'etre of tangibles is that you hold them in your hand (well, safe!) and that's the end of it - no "crisis", broker, regulation etc can take them away.  This is probably why historically all "wealthy families" in all socio-historic settings, have held a large amount of their wealth in physical tangibles (ie - art, antiques, etc, as well as of course real estate, with the caveat that you only "own" real estate due to a sovereign power saying you do).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are indeed [art funds](https://www.google.com/search?q=art+funds), which are essentially mutual funds that buy and sell works of art.